# Consulta semanal php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

tengo un proyecto y necesito organizar resultados semanales en una tabla.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>tabla semanal</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
 <tr>
  <th>EMPLEADO</th>
  <th>LUNES<br>(fecha)</th>
  <th>MARTES<br>(fecha)</th>
  <th>MIERCOLES<br>(fecha)</th>
  <th>JUEVES<br>(fecha)</th>
  <th>VIERNES<br>(fecha)</th>
  <th>SABADO<br>(fecha)</th>
  <th>DOMINGO<br>(fecha)</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>JUAN</td>
  <td>56</td>
  <td>67</td>
  <td>34</td>
  <td>23</td>
  <td>25</td>
  <td>78</td>
  <td>90</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>PEDRO</td>
  <td>90</td>
  <td>67</td>
  <td>45</td>
  <td>56</td>
  <td>34</td>
  <td>33</td>
  <td>56</td>
 </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

este es el código en php, me funciona vertical pero quiero organizarlos:

```html
<?php 
include 'conexion.php';
$sql = mysqli_query($conect, "SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE fecha 
  BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE()-7 AND CURRENT_DATE() ORDER by fecha DESC");    
  echo '<table border="2">
   <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Fecha</th>
   <th>i</th>
       
    </tr>';
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
     echo'<tr>
      <td>'.$row ['id'].'</td>
      <td>'.$row ['nombre'].'</td>
      <td>'.$row ['fecha'].'</td>
      <td>'.$row ['item'].'</td>
       
     </tr>';}'
</table>'; 
    

 ?>
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Puedes explicar un poco más que es lo que necesitas. No queda claro el problema ni lo que quieres obtener exactamente.

Comment: Quiero realizar una consulta de una tabla con resultados de los últimos 7 días y que estén en el orden como lo describí en el html (lunes, martes miércoles, jueves, viernes, etc.) sólo llegue hacer la consulta de los 7 últimos días pero no se como organizarlos en el orden.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 
///primero haces una consulta 
$sql = mysqli_query($conect, "SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE fecha 
        BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE()-7 AND CURRENT_DATE() ORDER by fecha DESC");



//en este array almacenaremos los datos
$dia = array();

//determinamos  la fecha de primer y untimo dia de la semana

$primer_dia = time();
$ultimo_dia = time();
while(date("w",$primer_dia)!=1){
$primer_dia -= 3600;
}
while(date("w",$ultimo_dia)!=0){
$ultimo_dia += 3600;
}

/////recoremos la consulta usando una variable temporal
foreach($sql as $sqltmp):

//filtamos los del lunes
if( $sqltmp -> fecha < date('Y-m-d',$primer_dia+1*24*3600)) {
    $dia[0]  += array ($sqltmp;);
  }else{

//filtamos  los del marte
if( $sqltmp -> fecha < date('Y-m-d',$primer_dia+2*24*3600)) {
    $dia[1]  += array ($sqltmp;);
  }else{

//filtamos  los del miercoles
if( $sqltmp -> fecha < date('Y-m-d',$primer_dia+3*24*3600)) {
    $dia[2]  += array ($sqltmp;);
  }else{

//filtamos  los del jueves
if( $sqltmp -> fecha < date('Y-m-d',$primer_dia+4*24*3600)) {
    $dia[3]  += array ($sqltmp;);
  }else{

//filtamos  los del viernes
if( $sqltmp -> fecha < date('Y-m-d',$primer_dia+5*24*3600)) {
    $dia[4]  += array ($sqltmp;);
  }else{

//filtamos  los del ...
if( $sqltmp -> fecha < date('Y-m-d',$primer_dia+6*24*3600)) {
    $dia[5]  += array ($sqltmp;);
  }else{

//filtamos  los del domingo
if( $sqltmp -> fecha < date('Y-m-d',$primer_dia+7*24*3600)) {
    $dia[6]  += array ($sqltmp;);
     }
                     }
                 }
              }
           }
       } 
 }
endforeach;
?>
//ya t
```

esta separados, los tienes que mostrarlos espero te ayude

Comment: Esta respuesta ha sido marcada como de muy baja calidad por la comunidad y no termina de quedar claro qué es lo que hace o en qué consiste. Deberías editarla para añadir una descripción detallada de la solución para que sea de utilidad a otros usuarios. Lee [answer] para más información.